# No emulators showing up for in the Run menu for UWP app. :(

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, emulation, windows-10-mobile

I'm building a UWP app and want to test it out on a mobile emulator.

I've installed the newest SDK and Mobile Emulator found here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

I've also installed all the packages I would assume needed in Visual Studio 2017, but no emulator options are showing up in my run menu.. I have updated to the newest version of Visual Studio and even tried the same things in the preview, but with no luck.

I believe I have the right settings enabled in my BIOS and I'm currently running VS2017 on a Windows 10 Educational PC updated to the newest version.

I don't get why I'm not seeing any emulator options??

Answer (score 0):

1. run visual studio installer
2. Select individual components
3. Uninstall all emulator in the emulators(this step is option, but I've found out few times I nee uninstall first before install the emulator)
4. Install necessary emulator which you need.
5. Make sure you are on dev mode in windows 10 and switch on hyper-V

[image]

Comment: Hey Miao - I'll test that out tomorrow. What options do you have in your run-menu?

Comment: I figured out the problem - I am targeting a version of Windows that is too high. Wish Microsoft would get their mobile emulators updated to match the latest version..

Comment: @Nicksen Microsoft no longer provides the same build to desktop and mobile. mobile hangs in a feature2 branch with less features and lower buildnumber compared to Fall Creators update for Desktop

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to select the correct build platforms. When ARM is selected there no Simulator available in the Run sub menu. But when I selected Any CPU, x86 or x64, the Simulator appeared.

As Miao say, you need to install the simulator from the Visual Studio Installer